# Consume Json api format in emberjs

Tags: reactjs, json, ember.js, ember-data

```
data: [
       
    expiration-date: "2023-06-01T00:00:00"
    name: "Big Fish"
    id: "12932"
    membership-benefits: [{
            available-quantity: 0
            expiration-days: null
            expired-quantity: 0
            is-expired: false
            is-unlimited: false
            name: "Small Fish"
            status: {id: 2, name: "Active"}
            total-earned-quantity: 1
            used-quantity: 1
           }]
```

in model

```
@attr('string') name;
@attr('array') membershipBenefits;
@attr('string') expirationDate;
```

now when i m accessing the values :

```
console.log(model.name) /// Big Fish ✔️
console.log(model.expirationDate) /// 2023-06-01T00:00:00✔️
console.log(model.membershipBenefits[0].name) /// small Fish ✔️
console.log(model.membershipBenefits[0].status) ///  {id: 2, name: "Active"} ✔️
console.log(model.membershipBenefits[0].isUnlimited) /// undefined ❌
console.log(model.membershipBenefits[0].isExpired) /// undefined ❌
```

i am getting undefined value when i m accessing hyphenated properties of membershipBenefit array
What is the correct way to access these properties??????

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have a custom data format, have you seen thees docs for ember-data?: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/customizing-serializers/

To use a custom data format, you need to customize your serializer to know about that format

you'll likely also need to customize your adapter(s) for hyphenated -> camelCase (as hyphenated case are not valid JS identifiers): https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/customizing-adapters/